# PIRAMIDE DE NUMEROS C++

Tags: c++

AYUDA!
Necesito ayuda para realizar la siguiente piramide de numeros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo pero no logro concretarlo.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 5;
    for( int i=1;i<=n; i++){
        for(int j=1; j<=i;j++){
            cout<<j;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es exáctamente el problema?

Comment: @abril figueroa Si todavia no encuentras la solución, quizas en un rato eche un ojo al problema.

Comment: osea si tiene la forma pero los numeros no son los que quiero, quiero que sean 1 y 0

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te hace falta es añadir un condicional que verifique en que columna y en que fila estas para que así puedas ubicar los ceros y los unos.

Si la fila 'i' es par entonces:  si la columna 'j' es par escribe 1, si la columna 'j' es impar escribe 0.

Si la fila 'i' es impar entonces:  si la columna 'j' es par escribe 0, si la columna 'j' es impar escribe 1.

El código que soluciona tu problema es el siguiente:
Si la respuesta te ha servido de ayuda por favor márcala como la respuesta correcta:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 5;
    for( int i=0; i<=n; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<=i; j++) {
            if (i%2 == 0) {
                if(j % 2 == 0) {
                    cout<<1;
                } else {
                    cout<<0;
                }
            } else {
                if(j % 2 == 0) {
                    cout<<0;
                } else {
                    cout<<1;
                }
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```